# How to change a theme in Windows 7 with a PowerShell script?

Tags: windows-7, powershell, themes

I would like to have a script that would change the current theme of Windows 7. I found the registry entry where this stored, but I apparently need to take some further action to get Windows to load the theme. What should I do?

Here is the script that I'm trying to use, but it isn't working (registry updated, but theme not changed):

```
######################################
# Change theme by updating registry. #
######################################

# Define argument which defines which theme to apply. 
param ( [string] $theme = $(Read-Host -prompt "Theme") )

# Define the themes we know about.
$knownThemes = @{ "myTheme" = "mytheme.theme"; "alien" = "oem.theme" }

# Identify paths to user themes.
$userThemes = " C:\Users\yoda\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\"

# Get name of theme file, based on theme provided
$themeFile = $knownThemes["$theme"]

# Build path to theme and set registry.
$newThemePath = "$userThemes$themeFile"
$regPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\"
Set-ItemProperty -path $regPath -name CurrentTheme -value $newThemePath

# Update system with this info...this isn't working!
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Stack Overflow question *[How do I change the current Windows theme programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546818)* dealing with the same issue. It seems like most commenters think you shouldn't be doing this at all (you may choose to ignore them). The other suggestions can be easily turned into a PowerShell script - just call the appropriate API functions.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve the problem with this code (tested in Windows 7 64bits)

```
# definition de la fonction native Windows permettant le test d'activation d'Aero
$def = @"

    [DllImport("dwmapi.dll", PreserveSig = false)]
    public static extern bool DwmIsCompositionEnabled();

"@
# chargement de la fonction native dans un namespace personnel
Add-Type -Namespace MaifCode -Name Aero -MemberDefinition $def


# fonction qui check si Aero est desactive ou non
function Check-Is-Aero{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> Test de la presence du mode Aero pour la session utilisateur $env:USERNAME"
    if([MaifCode.Aero]::DwmIsCompositionEnabled()){
        Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> Aero actif pour la session utilisateur $env:USERNAME"
        return $true
    }else{
        Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> Aero inactif pour la session utilisateur $env:USERNAME"
        return $false
    }
}

# fonction qui test si Aero est actif et le desactive dans ce cas
function Disable-Aero{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param()
    # test si aero actif
    If(Check-Is-Aero) {
        Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> Tentative de desactivation du mode Aero pour la session utilisateur $env:USERNAME"
        # desactivation du mode aero en passant sur le them par defaut
        try{
            Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "rundll32.exe" -ArgumentList "$env:SystemRoot\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL $env:SystemRoot\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\basic.theme"""
        }
        catch [exception]
        {
            # si erreur alors on sort et on affiche le message d'erreur
            Write-Error "Erreur dans l'execution de la desactivation du mode Aero : $error"
            exit -1
        }
        Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> Desactivation du mode Aero pour la session utilisateur $env:USERNAME terminee"
    }else{
        Write-Verbose "[$([DateTime]::Now)] ==> sortie du script sans action"
    }
}

# execution du code de desactivation
Disable-Aero -Verbose
# on sort
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OPs question directly, you can use the below. I've added some comments towards the end about the close mechanism you will find if you search this problem as they don't quite behave as a novice to scripting might believe they do.

I've also slightly improved the state of the art in that the solution is pure powershell (albeit with calls to com objects) and the delay before closing the window configures itself based on the state of the desktop.

```
#the path to the theme we want to apply
$ThemePath = "C:\Windows\Resources\Ease of Access Themes\classic.theme"

#the name of the desktop customization window (Written for windows 7, change for your flavor)
$CustomizationWindowName = "Personalization"

$myWScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell #wscriptshell com object to interact with the system
$myShellApplication = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application #shellapplication com object to access window names

#execute the theme change
$myWScriptShell.Run("rundll32.exe %SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL %SystemRoot%\system32\desk.cpl desk,@Themes /Action:OpenTheme /file:""$ThemePath""")

#this while block continuously searches for the 
#customization window which will be left behind based on it's name
:search while($true) 
{
    #enumerate the open windows
    foreach($window in $myShellApplication.Windows())
    {
        #check each window to see if it's the one of interest
        #when we find the window, break from the outer 
        #"search" loop to execute the remainder of the script
        if($window.LocationName -eq $CustomizationWindowName){break search} 
    }
}

#activate the customization window (in case it's in the background,
#and to be sure we send the keys to the right window)
$myWScriptShell.AppActivate($CustomizationWindowName)

#This is alt+F+C, intended for file->Close. 
#Presumably pulled from another (perhaps office?) script
#In the common literature, this line actually did the close, #the last line was essentially doing nothing
#$myWScriptShell.SendKeys("%FC") #commented as extraneous

#In the common literature, this was just {F4}, which doesn't work without the % for "alt". 
#The prior line actually did the work.
$myWScriptShell.SendKeys("%{F4}")
```